# What are the steps used in symfony constraint validation

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I was reading this

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/NotNull.html

```
// src/Acme/BlogBundle/Entity/Author.php
namespace Acme\BlogBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Author
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     */
    protected $firstName;
}
```

Now i want to know that when i submit the `form` and my `firstname` is `null`

and i try to save it. Then in which sequence the validation is performed. I mean

1. I mean when the symfony reads the not null annotation and how does it reads it
2. What exact steps / files it uses to check that

Answer (score 0):

The formBuilder will handle the html5 validation based on the nullable field property and field type (or if you specify required => false).

`$form->isValid()` will check all class constraints and / or specific rules passed as parameters to the formBuilder